# Quantum Time Crystals

Tags: quantum-mechanics, symmetry, time, symmetry-breaking, time-crystals

I am not sure I appreciate the implication made by Wilczek [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1202.2539):

[image]

I definitely see how the expectation value for $\dot\phi$ becomes zero for an energy eigenstate $\Psi_E$ but I do not see what he is saying about precluding an order parameter.  In fact, the best definition of an order parameter I can find says it is any observable that can be used to detect phase transitions.  I assume he's referring to a change of state from time translation symmetry invariant to broken time translation symmetry, but the exact nature of the omitted implication is not clear to me.  Can you tell me what he means?

Comment: More on [symmetry breaking in time crystals](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/symmetry-breaking+time-crystals).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He is referring to a more precise definition of order parameter. The idea is to capture spontaneous symmetry breaking: the ground states of the system are not individually invariant under the symmetries of the Hamiltonian (plural since the lowest energy eigenspace necessarily is). This leads to the notion of order parameter, it is the expected value of an observable which is trivial before SSB and non-trivial after. For example, for a ferromagnetic material, magnetization is the order parameter of the spontaneously broken rotational symmetry.

The problem raised here is that any expected value of an observable on a ground state is time independent, so the time derivative of such an observable which would be the order parameter is always trivial. Hope this helps and tell me if you need more detail.

Comment: Thanks.  He is using $\phi$ as an arbitrary order parameter then.  Could you clarify what you mean by "plural since the lowest energy eigenspace necessarily is"?

Comment: Technically $\dot{\mathcal O}$ so that it is zero in the time invariant phase. Each energy eigenspace is invariant by the symmetry group of the Hamiltonian. Since under ssb the symmetries act non trivially on the states, the eigenspace is necessarily nondegenerate.